# How to make white whip cream?

Tags: cake, cream, whipped-cream

I'm trying to make a regular circular cake with cream in the middle and top. A lot of recipe online will just tell you to whip the cream from a mix if sugar and heavy cream.

I did that, it works but the whip cream done this way is yellowish. Well the heavy cream is yellowish to begin with and I tried a couple of brands same thing.

This is different from white cream that you would buy out of a spray can. Pure white.

Is there a way to make pure white whip cream at home?

Comment: I woudn't be surprised if there are extra processing steps in making canned whipped cream.  You can try a cake shop for white food coloring (it's usually a powder for white), if you can't find any non-yellow cream.

Answer (score 1):

Heavy cream can vary in color depending on the feed given to cows and the breed of cow.  Where I am, it's rare to find heavy cream that's very yellow, so my whipped cream usually is white enough that it's not a problem.  (It's not generally *bright* white, but not noticeably yellow.)

If you can't find white cream, as Joe mentioned in a comment, try white food coloring.  I've usually seen it in paste or liquid form, but powdered versions exist too.  If you can't find it in a grocery store, it's available online (and your local bakery might be willing to sell you some).  I've never used it for whipped cream, but it's the common remedy for icings when you want them to be bright white rather than the off-white/light yellow you might get with a traditional buttercream made with a lot of (yellow) butter.